python argparse alternating positional arguments
I would like to alternate positional arguments at the end of the arguments in groups of 2 (but I would also like to know how to it in groups of any number). e.g.:
my_program -o optional file destination [file destination ...]

If there is a <file> but no <destination>, then this should be considered wrong. How should this be done, or is it not possible using argparse?

What do you want the resulting namespace to look like? Really, the best you can do is accept an arbitrary number of positional arguments, but when you define p.add_argument('fd_pairs', nargs='*', action=FDPairs), the __call__ method of the FDPairs class can take care of verifying the list of arguments has even length, and break it down into something like [(file, destination), (file, destination), ..] as desired.

I'd just accept a single nargs='*', and split the resulting list of strings after parsing.  If it helps your users you could write a custom usage.

my_program -o optional -p file destination -p file destination ... would be much easier to write a parser for, at the expense of making invocation slightly more verbose.

Flagged/optionals can be repeated if the action is 'append'.  Positionals cannot be repeated

@chepner the namespace argparse acceptes else with spaces beetween the arguments. Also an odd number of arguments would be wrong. So of course there are other possibilities but argparse checks for other stuff too which is convenient and I do would like to have it as positional because I think it is straighforward in this case

You have to choose between a format that argparse can handle and writing your own code to process an arbitrary list of positional arguments.

@chepner ok so you want to say me that it is not possible with argparse? In this case that is indeed the best answer

The easy answer would seem to be using nargs='*' and then assert len(args.filedest) % 2 == 0, or some more friendly check.  It's not going to be automatic.
